# How to count how many words have a given letter in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to solve an easy problem in other programming languages, but I can't handle it on PL/SQL. I have to mention that I'm beginner in PL/SQL.

The problem sound like this: I have a string with many words separated by spaces and I must count how many words have the letter "u" in their composition.

I did something to this problem, but isn't what I'm looking for. In my code I count how many "u" are in the all string. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
set serveroutput on;
 DECLARE
    v_sir VARCHAR2(225) := 'grass car unity united car until'; 
    v_I NUMBER := 1; 
    v_count NUMBER := 0; 
 BEGIN 
    WHILE v_I <= LENGTH(v_sir) 
    LOOP 
       IF substr(v_sir, v_I, 1) IN ('u', 'U') THEN 
          v_count := v_count + 1; 
       END IF; 
       v_I := v_I + 1; 
    END LOOP;  
 dbms_output.put_line('The number of "u" is: ' || v_count); 
 END;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  v_sir   VARCHAR2(225) := 'grass car unity united car until unusual'; 
  v_count NUMBER        := REGEXP_COUNT( v_sir, '\S*u\S*' );
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('The number of words containing "u" is: ' || v_count);
END;
/
```

Outputs `4`

Comment: I like the O(1) approach. I was about to post my answer as a SQL to split the string by a space as delimiter and then `INSTR` check for 'u' and then `COUNT(*)`. But I think that would be nowhere close to this.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression approach is simple, and doesn't need any PL/SQL at all - you could just call it from plain SQL. But if you're doing this as an exercise and really want to do it the hard brute-force way you could loop over the characters in the string, looking for spaces (or any other whitespace character if you want) to find word boundaries, and only count the appearances of the 'u's in words you haven't already seen:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  v_sir varchar2(225) := 'grass car unity united car until unused nu'; 
  v_word_has_u boolean := false;
  v_count number := 0; 
begin 
  for v_i in 1..length(v_sir) loop
    if substr(v_sir, v_i, 1) = ' ' then
      -- new word; can look for other whitespace characters too
      -- reset flag so we start looking for 'u's again
      v_word_has_u := false;
    elsif v_word_has_u then
      -- already counted this word
      continue;
    elsif substr(v_sir, v_i, 1) in ('u', 'U') then 
      -- first u/U in the word we're looking at, so incremment counter
      v_count := v_count + 1;
      -- set flag so we don't count any more from this word
      v_word_has_u := true;
    end if; 
  end loop;  
  dbms_output.put_line('The number of words with "u" is: ' || v_count);
end; 
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

The number of words with "u" is: 5
```

But this is purely as an exercise, there's no reason to do anything like this in the real world when there is built-in functionality you can use.